# Remove hyperlink to edit post in edit.php

Tags: posts

How can I remove the hyperlink to posts on the edit.php screen when listing all posts?

I am already removing the on hover links using the code below, but I want the actual post titles not to be hyperlinked at all.

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 1 );
function remove_row_actions( $actions )
{
    if( get_post_type() === 'wprss_feed_item' )
        unset( $actions['edit'] );
        unset( $actions['view'] );
        unset( $actions['trash'] );
        unset( $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] );
    return $actions;
}
```

I also tried adding a column instead of the title column, and then echoing get_the_title() within that column. However in that case, although I would get rid of the hyperlink, I would lose the WP functionality that adds the quick links for trashing, editing etc. beneath the post title.

I also tried the following with no success:

```
add_filter( 'edit_post_link', 'remove_hyperlink_from_food_titles');

function remove_hyperlink_from_food_titles() {
    if ( 'edit-food_item' !== get_current_screen()->id )
    return;   

    return get_the_title();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the a tag with javascript, short and easy.
Use the follow plugin; include a small script in the footer of the `edit.php`, only this page in backend of WP and remove all a-tag inside the table; see the selector on the source below.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Remove a
 * Version:     0.0.1
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65613/
 * Description: 
 * Author:      Frank Bültge
 * Author URI:  http://bueltge.de
 */

if ( ! function_exists( 'wpse65613_remove_a' ) ) {

    add_action( 'admin_footer-edit.php', 'wpse65613_remove_a' );

    function wpse65613_remove_a() {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery('table.wp-list-table a.row-title').contents().unwrap();
        </script>
        <?php
    }

}
```

The result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

All you're searching for is right inside [`~/wp-admin/includes/screen.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.2/wp-admin/includes/screen.php).

We even got a tag for it: [screen-columns](/questions/tagged/screen-columns).

If you can't around it, you can still use a silly solution. Replace the link with `#` and change the CSS styles.

```
<?php
! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) AND exit;
/** Plugin Name: (#65629) »kaiser« Change WP List Table row title */

function wpse65629_row_title_styles()
{
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        #the-list .row-title {
            cursor: default;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #555;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_head-edit.php', 'wpse65629_row_title_styles' );

function wpse65629_change_row_title( $url, $post_id, $context )
{
    if ( 'edit-post' !== get_current_screen()->id )
        return;

    return '#';
}
add_filter( 'get_edit_post_link', 'wpse65629_change_row_title', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Still can't find a way to remove the hyperlink, I only arrived till removing a column completely.

Comment: I don't think that is what @drtanz is asking.  Granted, I only just looked through screen.php (thinking it would help with an issue I am having), but it seems totally unrelated to changing how the title column is displayed.  As far as I know (which may not be far) there is no way to alter the switch cases for the `single_row()` method of `WP_List_Table`. You can add columns but not change existing ones.

Comment: @helgatheviking For you a quick fix. See update.

Comment: @kaiser thanks I see how this works now. I tried using the edit_post_link filter, as I am trying to eliminate the link completely (no a tags), and I posted the code in my update to the original question. Didn't work however, is it not possible to use that filter here?

Comment: @drtanz A look at the source will answer your question.

Comment: @kaiser Can you elaborate on that? Is it only usable for posts?

Comment: @drtanz **Please** take a look at the source. Tell yourself the following question: Why is there a check/return on the `get_current_screen()->id`. I'm pretty sure that you'll get around that.

Comment: @kaiser, I am referring to the code I posted in the original question, and am asking why it doesn't work when using the edit_post_link filter. I fully understand how the code you provided in the answer works. I'm just interested in why using the other hook things don't work.

Comment: Please come to chat for such discussion and ping me there. This post is already flagged by the community user.